# Why Android Native class Html does not support transparent background?

Tags: android, html, background-color

In my app I use `BackgroundColorSpan` and print the result on `TextView` by using the `Html.java`. Here is a html sample string I try to print:

```html
<html><body><p><span style=\"color:#000000;\"><span style=\"background-color:#0;\"><u>Test</u></span></span></p></body></html>
```

When I try to print, it looks so:

[image: Print on TextView]

This issue happens only when using the TRASPARENT color, other colors are printed/r well. It seems the `TextView` class does not support transparent color rendering. How can I handle that?

One more issue is that the `BackgroundColorSpan` overrides the highlight color when selecting the text. To this issue I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783682/backgroundcolorspan-adjust-height-or-add-a-padding-to-it), but did not really help.

Comment: "It seems the Html class does not support transparent color rendering" -- `Html` does not render anything. `Html` converts HTML to a `Spanned` object, which in turn is rendered by `TextView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, exectly. However, this could mean that the problem is in textview, is not? When it renders, then it somehow can't deal with when I comes to the transparent color.

Comment: "However, this could mean that the problem is in textview, is not?" -- that or `BackgroundColorSpan`, which is what `background-color` maps to. Your question is focused on `Html`, though, particularly in terms of the title. This may limit your answers.

Comment: `#0` is not a valid color value. Hexadecimal colors should either be 3 or 6 characters long for RGB, or 4 or 8 characters long for RGBA (without the # of course).

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy actually, that value is valid and even you can get it when calling `Color.TRANSPARENT`. However, if you take a dipper look inti this one `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`, this has the value `#00000000`. Both cases are not rendered. But if you put the above html string [here](https://jsonformatter.org/html-viewer) and run it, the result is exactly that one (both values are accepted) I try to achieve in Android on `TextView`.

Comment: The problem lies within the `Html` class that interprets the HTML source. No matter what you put in there, the alpha value will always be set 0xFF (fully opaque): `color | 0xFF000000` (Android uses ARGB). If the provided color string cannot be represented by an Integer, say #FFFFFFFF, it will not render the background (fully transparent).